# Error while using php variable in a query string

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to pass the return value of a php function through query string but its not working. Please look into the code below:

Here I'm trying to replace $myvar in the query string.

```
<button onClick="parent.location='http://www.example.com&id=$myvar'">Design Your product</button>
```

The php function to retrieve $myvar is given below:

```
<?php
$myvar=Design();
function Design() 
 {
// my function code

return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<button onClick="parent.location='http://www.example.com&id=<?php echo $myvar; ?>'">Design Your product</button>
```

Comment: Thanx 4 ur immediate help but i'm still getting error. It says **"Call to undefined funtion Design()"** 

Have i made mistake in the function call ??
    
    <?php
    $myvar=Design();
    function Design() 
    {
    // my function code
  
    return $result;
     }

Comment: See Trogvar's answer - You must tell the preprocessor what the definition of the function is _before_ you call it. Setting $myvar to Design() before the actual function is defined results, predictably, in a **Call to undefined function Design()**.

Answer (score 0):

You try to call the function before it has been defined. This should work

```
<?php
    function Design()
    {
         return "something";
    }
    $myvar = Design();
?>
<button onClick="parent.location='http://www.example.com?id=<?php echo $myvar; ?>'">Design Your product</button>
```